# Resaltar campo input seleccionado en JS

Tags: javascript, input, blur, focus

Buen día. Necesito saber cómo puedo resaltar un campo que seleccione en JS dando click en el mismo (osea que el background cambie de color). Ya lo logré pero tengo que escribir por cada input que tenga en mi página HTML, quisiera sabe cómo se le hace para agregar todos los inputs. Gracias. Dejo mi código a continuación.

```
'use strict'
var input = document.querySelector("#usuario");
input.addEventListener("focus", function() {
input.style.background = "#fbf8ec";
});
input.addEventListener("blur", function() {
 input.style.background = "#e1e1e1";
});
var input2 = document.querySelector("#password");
input2.addEventListener("focus", function() {
input2.style.background = "#fbf8ec";
});
input2.addEventListener("blur", function() {
input2.style.background = "#e1e1e1";
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Para aplicar lo mismo a todos los input puedes usar:

```
document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach((input) => {
    input.addEventListener("focus", function() {
        input.style.background = "#fbf8ec";
    });
});
```

Comment: Se me había olvidado cerrar la función anónima del focus

Answer (score 1):

Ya estás bien encaminado y de hecho la respuesta que ya te dio @Benito-B es buena (por eso le he dado el +1), yo solamente cambiaría el evento `focus` por los eventos `focusin` y `focusout` para que solamente se "pinte" el `input` en cuestión, quedaría así:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach((input) => {
    input.addEventListener('focusin', (event) => {
  event.target.style.background = '#fbf8ec';    
  });
});

document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach((input) => {
    input.addEventListener('focusout', (event) => {
  event.target.style.background = '';    
  });
});
```

```html
<input placeholder="input 1"/>
<input placeholder="input 2"/>
<input placeholder="input 3"/>
```